# Alter saturation or brightness of a color

Tags: color

I'm using xcolor.sty's nifty wheel function to define a color scheme based on a single base color. So, for example:

```
\definecolor{base}{HTML}{AADD96}
\colorlet{complement}{base>wheel,1,3}
```

makes `base` a pale green color, and `complement` a similarly pale blue (1/4 of the way round the color wheel).

Is there a way to similarly define colors by changing the *saturation* or *brightness* of an existing color?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `\definecolorseries`:

```
\definecolor{base}{HTML}{AADD96}
\definecolorseries{moresaturated}{hsb}{step}{base}{0,0.2,0}
\resetcolorseries{moresaturated}
```

will let you use `moresaturated!![1]` for a somewhat more saturated colour, `moresaturated!![2]` for an even more saturated one, and so on. (But beware overflow: once the saturation reaches 1, it's reset to zero. Here `moresaturated!![4]` is less saturated than `base`.)

Obviously you can use the same trick to go down in saturation, or up or down in brightness.