# Use hsb color model

Tags: color

How do you define colors using hsb color parameters? I need a certain hue and want to fiddle with the saturation and the brightness. The xcolor package documentation does not explain how to use `\definecolor` with the hsb model. In fact, it's more by chance that I managed to use it with rgb, which is RGB in xcolor.

So, what I am trying to do, in short is this

```
\definecolor{bgsbrown}{RGB}{235,172,59}
\definecolor{bgsdarkbrown}{RGB}{191,124,0}
```

but using hsb (which apparently doesn't work that way):

```
\definecolor{bgsbrown}{hsb}{26,196,138}
\definecolor{bgsdarkbrown}{hsb}{26,240,90}
```

The obvious advantage is that the hue (26) stays the same and I can alter saturation and brightness and have a consistent color model in my document.

Now don't get me wrong, I don't want to use exactly these commands, I just want to know how to use the hsb color model the correct way in LaTeX.

An MWE to play with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{bgsbrown}{RGB}{235,172,59}
\definecolor{bgsdarkbrown}{RGB}{191,124,0}

\definecolor{bgsbrownhsb}{hsb}{26,196,138}
\definecolor{bgsdarkbrownhsb}{hsb}{26,240,90}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill [bgsbrown] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \fill [bgsdarkbrown] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);
        \fill [bgsbrownhsb] (0,1) rectangle (1,2);
        \fill [bgsdarkbrownhsb] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the corresponding output:

[image: a fuchsia rectangle on top of a lighter and a darker brown square]

Oh, btw, I looked at

[defining new color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339014/defining-new-color)

[How to make correct shading with hsb color model?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59198/how-to-make-correct-shading-with-hsb-color-model)

[Alter saturation or brightness of a color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22784/alter-saturation-or-brightness-of-a-color)

[TikZ won't support HSB color model hsb in article document class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230483/tikz-wont-support-hsb-color-model-hsb-in-article-document-class)

[Colors in xcolor and color models](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225331/colors-in-xcolor-and-color-models)

but either I didn't understand what they were trying to tell me, or they don't provide the solution to the way how to use hsb color parameters.

**EDIT**: PaulGaborit's comment lead to

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{fakebrownhsb}[rgb]{HSB}{26,196,138}
\definecolor{fakedarkbrownhsb}[rgb]{HSB}{26,240,90}

\definecolor{bgsbrownhsb}{HSB}{26,196,138}
\definecolor{bgsdarkbrownhsb}{HSB}{26,240,90}

\definecolor{bgsbrown}{RGB}{235,172,59}
\definecolor{bgsdarkbrown}{RGB}{191,124,0}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
        \fill [fakebrownhsb] (0,2) rectangle (1,3);
        \fill [fakedarkbrownhsb] (1,2) rectangle (2,3);
        \fill [bgsbrownhsb] (0,1) rectangle (1,2);
        \fill [bgsdarkbrownhsb] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
        \fill [bgsbrown] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \fill [bgsdarkbrown] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(I changed the order of the definitions and the order of the drawn objects in the source so they match the tikzpicture from top to bottom)

with output

[image]

Comment: I use XeLaTeX to compile, if that's of any concern ;)

Comment: Look for table 3, p.10, `xcolor` documentation: `HSB` uses values between 0 and 240 (`hsb` uses values between 0 and 1).

Comment: Note: to avoid conversion by the PDF viewer and use only rgb color, you can use the optional parameter: `\definecolor{bgsbrownhsb}[rgb]{HSB}{26,196,138}`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit huh... the problem is a different one, then. I replaced `hsb` by `HSB` and the mwe works. My main document still won't compile, but it seems `tcolorbox` is being picky about color models. `! Package pgf Error: Unsupported color model 'hsb'. Sorry.` Is there another way of staying with one hue and adjusting saturation and brightness, when using PGF? That would answer the original question, too.

Comment: Try the solution in my second comment...

Comment: @PaulGaborit I added your suggestion to the question. The solution in your second comment won't give any other output than the four brown square depicted at the end of the question. Now, I don't wanna say I don't understand color spaces, because I really don't, but is there a way to keep more or less the screen colors produced by the rgb parameters? I mean translate to hsb and get similar output. Or is hsb actually a print color and I can expect the print results to look just as pretty as what I get on screen when I use the rgb parameters?

Comment: I printed the mwe and the on-screen representation is actually not so bad. The top squares are no different from the center squares. The bottom square are noticeably ligher and more luminous than the upper four squares. I guess the printer corrects the colors on its own from rgb to cmyk (like it should).

Comment: My second comment is a solution to the problem with `tcolorbox`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit unfortunately, not, I'm afraid. PGF still moans about `hsb` not being defined. Wheter I use `\definecolor{BrownHSB}[rgb]{HSB}{26,180,220}` and `\definecolor{DarkBrownHSB}[rgb]{HSB}{26,240,180}` or `\definecolor{BrownHsb}[rgb]{Hsb}{39,0.75,0.92}` and `\definecolor{DarkBrownHsb}[rgb]{Hsb}{39,1,.75}` doesn't change a thing: tcolorbox throws an error. And even though the document compiles, the shading in the tcolorbox is not from <color> to white, which is unfortunate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77889/discussion-between-thymaro-and-paul-gaborit).